# How to prove that SSH encrypts data and Telnet does not?

Tags: ssh, telnet

SSH encrypts data, and Telnet sends data in plain text
can someone give an example of data transfer?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup 2 machines to communicate with each other through ssh and telnet and route them through [wireshark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) to check the packets and determine if they are encripted

Comment: Thanks you@!
You helped me a lot